# Monaco editor with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, monaco-editor

Getting this error when using monaco editor with next js.
Have anyone resolved this?

````
Failed to compile
./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/actionbar/actionbar.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/css-npm
Location: node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/actionbar/actionbar.js```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this webpack config fixed it for me

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin());
    return config;
  },
  cssLoaderOptions: { url: false }
})
```

Comment: I tried this on `"@zeit/next-css": "1.0.1", "next": "11.0.1",` and dev server failed with `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'styles' of undefined`. `@zeit/next-css` appears deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

**`@monaco-editor/react` third party helper**

I'm not sure why it works, I would rather avoid third party stuff, but this is he first thing I got to work, they just package it so nicely, so here it is:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@monaco-editor/react
- https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react

you can get rid of `MonacoWebpackPlugin` when using that.

Key dependencies I tested with:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@monaco-editor/react": "4.2.1",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "monaco-editor": "0.26.1",
```

Then usage is as described on README. They expose a `Editor` component helper, but you can also get a `monaco` instance if you want.

Related:

- https://dev.to/swyx/how-to-add-monaco-editor-to-a-next-js-app-ha3
- https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor/issues/271
- https://github.com/resourcesco/snippets/blob/master/docs/monaco-editor-with-next.md
- https://github.com/react-monaco-editor/react-monaco-editor/issues/334
- https://github.com/ritz078/transform/issues/282

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in 2023 using Next.js 13.4.11 and monaco editor 0.40.0.

### Installation

```
npm install monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
npm install style-loader
npm install css-loader
```

### `next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const monacoRules = [
  {
    test: /\.ttf$/,
    type: 'asset/resource'
  }
]

module.exports = {
  webpack: (
    config,
    { isServer }
  ) => {

    // Modify config and then return it
    if(!isServer) {
      console.log(config)
      config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ["javascript", "markdown", "yaml"],
        filename: "static/[name].worker.js",
      }))
      config.module.rules.push(...monacoRules)
    }

    return config
  },
}
```

### `MyClientComponent.js`

```
"use client"

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';

export default function MyEditor() {
  const [editor, setEditor] = useState(null)
  const editorRef = useRef(null)

  // Instantiate Monaco Editor
  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      value: "# Hello World",
      language: 'markdown'
    }
    const myEditor = monaco.editor.create(editorRef.current, options);
    setEditor(myEditor)
    return () => { editor.dispose() }
  }, [editorRef])

  return (
    <div ref={ editorRef }></div>
  )
}
```

**Note the import statement** `import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api'`.

`import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'` gave me the error

> Error: Unexpected usage at EditorSimpleWorker.loadForeignModule (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/common/services/editorSimpleWorker.js:523:31)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/services/webWorker.js:44:30)
> at async eval (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/typescript/tsMode.js:116:16)

when using `language: 'javascript'`.