# How to run the Monaco editor from a CDN like cdnjs?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am struggling a bit to find a minimal runnable example that just runs from the CDN, as opposed to the existing in-tree examples which mostly use local servers.

Answer (score 34):

After Googling a bit I found https://jsfiddle.net/developit/bwgkr6uq/ which just works with unpkg.com, and so I mostly just adapted it to cdnjs, here is a single working HTML file:

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Monaco editor</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
<script>
// require is provided by loader.min.js.
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs' }});
require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], () => {
  monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
    language: 'javascript',
    theme: 'vs-dark',
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Live: http://cirosantilli.com/_raw/web-cheat/monaco-editor.html

https://jsfiddle.net/developit/bwgkr6uq was also setting `window.MonacoEnvironment` to some hacky looking stuff, but things now seem to work without it.

**Using less loader magic**

Inspired from: [how to use monaco editor without node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099902/how-to-use-monaco-editor-without-node-js)

less-loader.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Monaco editor no loader</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/editor/editor.main.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script>var require = { paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs' } }</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/loader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.26.1/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
<script>
monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
  value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
  language: 'javascript',
  theme: 'vs-dark',
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Live: http://cirosantilli.com/web-cheat/monaco-editor-no-loader.html

**Do it without the loader**

Dedicated question: [how to use monaco editor without node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62099902/how-to-use-monaco-editor-without-node-js)

I don't know how to do it entirely without the ugly loader thing.

By looking at the Network inspector tab in Chrome, we see that the following are loaded when opening the above HTML:

- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/loader.min.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/language/typescript/tsMode.js
- https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/basic-languages/javascript/javascript.js

so we might try:

no-loader.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Monaco editor no loader TODO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/language/typescript/tsMode.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.20.0/min/vs/basic-languages/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script>
let editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
    language: 'javascript',
    theme: 'vs-dark',
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but that fails because all .js files rely on a global `define(` function being present, which is defined in the loader.

If we add the loader back to the above, the editor seems to work, but a bunch of errors show on the JavaScript console, as it appears that some of those files are trying to dynamically load other files in the local filesystem.

**Webpack integration**

For anything remotely serious, this will be the way to go.

Since their library distribution is so complex, they have this Webpack plugin to help: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin

Minimal example that seems to work fine, just note that there is a JavaScript error "Unexpected usage at EditorSimpleWorker.loadForeignModule" when running from `file://`: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/issues/157 so presumably the loader is still used for dynamic resources. Build and view:

```
npm install
npm run build
python3 -m http.server
```

and then visit http://localhost:8080

package.json

```
{
  "name": "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "5.2.4",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "monaco-editor": "0.26.1",
    "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "webpack": "5.36.1",
    "webpack-cli": "4.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'
// or import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api';
// if shipping only a subset of the features & languages is desired

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
  value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
  language: 'javascript',
  theme: 'vs-dark',
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Monaco editor webpack plugin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:400px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
<script src="dist/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This example could also be somewhat extracted from their upstream test under: https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin/tree/2459e4a023f9026ae5796a6e92f584c5d38e583e/test That test uses the `package.json` from the package itself however, and you have to extract some `devDependencies` from their into your own `package.json`, since they are not really `devDependencies`. Full run with:

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
cd monaco-editor-webpack-plugin
npm install
npm run prepublishOnly
npm test
chromium test/dist/index.html
```

A `mode: 'production'` build is extremely slow, about 50 seconds on my Lenovo P51.

`'development'` is much faster, only 5s, so the problem is presumably the optimization of all the assets.

The plugin offers options to select a subset of features to speed things up and make the bundle smaller, some I've tried:

- ```
  new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
    languages: ['javascript', 'typescript'],
  })
  ```

  Might save a few seconds, not very noticeable. As mentioned in the docs, `typescript` is mandatory when using `javascript`.
- `languages: [],`: 22s
- `languages: [], features: [],`: also 22s, `features: []` made no difference

**Get it to work with Next.js**

Just when I thought the fight was over... but no! The above webpack setup did not work with Next.js 11, was failing as asked at: [Monaco editor with nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773190/monaco-editor-with-nextjs/68611592#68611592) but I managed to work around by using: https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react

Answer (score 8):

**2023 Update:** If you don't need to target older browsers, the simplest way to do that is to just import it directly. You can use [jsdelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/) or [skypack](https://www.skypack.dev/).

No need for webpack or any extra loading logic.

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as monaco from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.39.0/+esm';

  monaco.editor.create(document.querySelector('.monaco'));
</script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vscode-codicons@0.0.17/dist/codicon.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="monaco" style="min-height: 100px"></div>
```

Comment: Can you share a working example using the code line you added here?

Comment: This works, but I don't see the editor `icons`, how to you manage to get the icon for this?
If you ``Ctrl + F`` in your snippet example, you will see no icons.

Comment: @KiddoV Good question. I updated the snippet to include the CSS for the icons.

Answer (score 4):

## Official Examples

- https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/tree/main/docs
- https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples

Specifically, you probably want https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/docs/integrate-amd-cross.md

### Example using Unpkg

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/vs' }});

  // Before loading vs/editor/editor.main, define a global MonacoEnvironment that overwrites
  // the default worker url location (used when creating WebWorkers). The problem here is that
  // HTML5 does not allow cross-domain web workers, so we need to proxy the instantiation of
  // a web worker through a same-domain script
  window.MonacoEnvironment = {
    getWorkerUrl: function(workerId, label) {
      return `data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(`
        self.MonacoEnvironment = {
          baseUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/'
        };
        importScripts('https://unpkg.com/monaco-editor@latest/min/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');`
      )}`;
    }
  };

  require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
    monaco.editor.create(document.querySelector('.monaco-editor-container'), {
      value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
      language: 'javascript',
      theme: 'vs-dark',
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Swapped to use cdnjs as unpkg is blocked in Egypt and other countries at the moment, but this code worked for me! None of the other answers worked, kept getting monaco is undefined. Thank you!