# Rails 7 import map couldn't find any packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import-maps

Hello I am new here in the rails world, the things is that I am playing with importmap, I am trying to install monako editor this way

```
./bin/importmap pin monaco-editor
```

But I got Couldn't find any packages in ["monaco-editor"] on jspm

I also tried this way but got error too

```
./bin/importmap pin monaco-editor --from unpkg
```

Any ideas of how to import monaco-editor in my project?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Add the following line to your `config/importmap.rb` manually instead of using the cli

```rb
pin 'monaco-editor', to: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.45.0/+esm'
```

If you are using stimulus you can get a simple monaco editor up and running like this

```js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'

export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    monaco.editor.create(this.element)
  }
}
```

## why does the importmaps command not just work?

importmaps relies on pure esm modules the browser can interpret directly without the need of a bundler. But the monaco-editor project is using the `import './actionbar.css';` syntax in their esm distribution. Since this is not yet in the javascript standard no browser currently supports that syntax (at least in 2023 check the [WICG proposal](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/645) and [webkits position](https://github.com/WebKit/standards-positions/issues/285) for updates). And thus also the importmaps command fails because the underlying api gets a javascript error on reading those lines. I personally got the following errors:

```
{"error":"Error: \n  \tfont-display: block;\n> \tsrc: url(./codicon.ttf) format(\"truetype\");\n                                              ^\n  }\n\nError parsing https://ga.jspm.io/npm:monaco-editor@0.45.0/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.css:9:45"}
```

```
{"error":"Error: Module not found: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.45.0/esm/vs/basic-languages/monaco.contribution imported from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.45.0/esm/vs/editor/editor.main.js"}
```

You can also check for your self if this still throws an error [here](https://generator.jspm.io/#U2VhYGBkDM0rySzJSU1hyM3PS0zO101NySzJL3Iw0DMx1TMAANcvMH8jAA). Maybe some day the javascript standard will be extended or microsoft will adapt their npm package to be browser compliant out of the box.

## The fix

@steventrouble [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76553340/6287070) the following code snippet with a cdn url which was pointing to a working esm module

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as monaco from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.39.0/+esm';

  monaco.editor.create(document.querySelector('.monaco'));
</script>
<div class="monaco" style="min-height: 100px"></div>
```

Sadly the +esm cdn link still serves the css that tries to load the microsoft own font. That is why the browser console will show the following error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/codicon.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

And the rails console will show this

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/codicon.ttf"):
```

Which is not too nice. But the editor still works fine and the font also looks good to me. But anyways I came up with an ugly hack to also get rid of that issue. That would be adding the following line to the `config/routes.rb` file

```rb
get 'codicon.ttf', to: redirect('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monaco-editor@0.45.0/esm/vs/base/browser/ui/codicons/codicon/codicon.ttf')
```