# Adding better lua(u) support for a monaco editor

Tags: lua, monaco-editor

I have a monaco editor [courtesy of this man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179813/how-to-run-the-monaco-editor-from-a-cdn-like-cdnjs), and I need to know how to add more advanced lua support to my Monaco editor that is using `less-loader.html` with a script tag to load the lua language: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.47.0/min/vs/basic-languages/lua/lua.min.js"></script>`, but when I load in the lua into the editor with the following script:

```html
<script>
      monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
        value: `function x() {
  console.log("Hello world!");
}`,
        language: 'lua', //lua is here since I dont have access to luau
        theme: 'vs-dark',
      });
</script>
<!-- i fixed the syntax -->
```

But when I set the language to 'lua', it only provides basic, as in minimal highligting, syntax for   globals like `local`, or `function`, and what I am trying to do is aquire further support for lua, as in luau (The coding language mainly used for roblox). This type of further support would be considered as highlighting similar items, example: I highlight the variable "foo", all other text containing "foo" would have a small, but apparent highlight. Another item for support would be underlines at coding errors (Aka. the red squiggles), and support for certain items like `--!nonstrict`. Thirdly (and finally), variables would have a seperate color from plaintext (white), comments would be greyed so not to confuse with code, exception being items like `--!nonstrict` or `--!strict`, functions/built-ins would be seperatly colored from regular items, such as `if then else while true false end` and yes, built-ins are (in my opinion) considered items such as `wait` or `:Connect`. With all of this, I do not want to implement monaco's IntelliSense feature, since it prevents the up and down arrow keys from  altering my position in the code, but instead scroll through the IntelliSense/Hints menu.

---

My current attempt on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grundigg/nw0sq5fd/) is working fine
exluding syntax, like how on the [original project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179813/how-to-run-the-monaco-editor-from-a-cdn-like-cdnjs), [Ciro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245/ciro-santilli-ourbigbook-com) has left a whitespace for the monaco  container, something I have fixed with a little styling, and have aquired the lua cdnjs.

But the solution I *tried* was loading a seperate language (lua), since my thought process was:

Since the loader requires the language javascript, what if I instead include the *lua* language and load *that* instead. I thought it would work with some advanced syntax.. Apparently not! instead I have minimal highlighting, no error hints (you know, the red sqiggles) and since I am not that advanced in coding, I have tried googling it alot, and no, I dont have an awnser yet.

-- Your personal worst coder in the world, chrom

Comment: "NO I DON'T WANT TO IMPLEMENT INTELLISENSE! its just very, very annoying"

You kinda forgot to mention what is that you _do_ want.

Comment: Yes I did, I want better syntax support without IntelliSense

Comment: You haven't really defined "better" though. Give an example of what you have now and what you'd like to have instead.

Comment: FWIW, you can simply check out the `monaco` demo here: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

If the Lua example here doesn't do what you want, you need something besides Monaco, like an LSP or other code analysis tooling.

Comment: Better: as in improved function, aka more capability, and sure I will check out the demo when I get home from school. Also what I *do* want to do is add better ( improved for you cubic ) syntaxes WITHOUT intellisense

Comment: Again, "improved function" is non-specific and thus pretty much non-answerable. You'll have to get a lot more concrete than that.

Comment: I have fixed my grammar problem solved.